# python-selenium how do I tell class="muted" buttons apart?

Tags: python, selenium

https://gyazo.com/c018faaba951401f6b0ddef5f1fce650
Here is a pic of the website and the html of it. As you can see there is a lot of `class="muted`" for each of the options to choose between. (yes, they are in my language.)

Luckily it's the first class="muted" that's the correct one. But how do I tell python to click that one? And what if it wasn't the first one I needed what then?

this doesn't work:

```
emner = browser.find_element_by_class_name('muted')
emner.click()
```

A video of me showing it: https://youtu.be/lXAaT-hsGbA

---

```
<li class="muted">
                            <strong><a href="/opret-annonce/?rubrikid=6120" data-bind="text: Name, attr: {href: Url, 'data-ga-act': $parent.analyticsAction, 'data-ga-lbl': Name}, click: $parent.handleClassification" data-ga-act="navigate-from-search" data-ga-lbl="Ure, barometere o.l.">Ure, barometere o.l.</a></strong> <small>
                                <span class="light">›</span> <span data-bind="text: CategoryName">Andre møbler og tilbehør</span> <span class="light">›</span> <span data-bind="text: SectionName">Til boligen</span>
                            </small>
                        </li>
```

which is:

                            **Ure, barometere o.l.** 
                                › Andre møbler og tilbehør › Til boligen

Comment: you'll get an answer much faster if you can share the HTML, preferably the URL. It might be that there is a lot more HTML inside the `li` element which needs to be clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION MYSELF, here is what works:

the two last lines should be like this:

```
emner = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Armbåndsure og lommeure')
emner.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
emner = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('muted')
```

returns a `list`.

If you want to click on the on first one, you would need to call

```
emner[0].click()
```

--

You don't want to click on the `li` element but on the link `a`. Try

```
emner.find_element_by_xpath(".//a").click()
```

Comment: ups i started with the code u wrote above without the element(s)...
withtout the s, just tried with the s and forgot to remove it again when I asked the question mb.
Tried what you just wrote, it didnt work either.

Comment: Got no error, U can look at the video too, just recorded it.

Comment: It didnt work but we are getting somewhere. I updated my "question" for the information how it went.
A little side note, even though it says thats its no clickable. It is... Which doesnt quite make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the document for all elements of a particular class using `find_elements_by_class_name()`. You get back a list of matching elements. You can then choose the right one if you know its index, or iterate over them looking for the one you need if there is some other characteristic that determines which one is "right."

Of course, if you know you want the first one, you just use `find_element_by_class_name()`, which gets just the first one.

See [the documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) for details.

Comment: Well the problem is I cant click the first little blue link under the big search space. 

The code I used is shown in the question above. and there is a pic for the information

Comment: Look carefully. You're calling `find_elements_by_class_name()`. Which returns a list. Then you're trying to click that list. Either get the first element of that list, or just use the singular `find_element_by_class_name()` instead.